# Is there a better method than ptrace for intercepting ("catching") Linux syscalls coming from a forked process?

Tags: linux, system-calls, fork, ptrace

I would like to catch all syscalls coming from a forked process, modify them, send them to the kernel, and then pass them back to the forked process. Is this possible, and if so, how might I go about this?
I've done some research, and found ptrace, but it seems a bit heavy weight because it does so many things (modifying registers, etc...). Correct me if I am incorrect, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can wait for version 5.11 of the kernel, it will have [a new system call interception mechanism](https://lwn.net/Articles/826313/) designed for fast (or less slow) emulation of system calls. The initial use case is for Wine but it is usable for other purposes, as long as a signal handler can work (it relies on `SIGSYS`).

Comment: Thanks! I think for now I'll stick with ptrace, and then once 5.11 is out for a good amount of time, I'll upgrade my laptop and do that instead.